# calculate roots with negative power and two variables

Tags: polynomials, roots

i want to calculate roots for following equation. which has $2$ variables $x$ and $h$, where $h$ has some negative power.
$h^2*A+144*h^{-1/2}*B=0$
where $A$ and $B$ both are some function of $x$.
I want roots of $h$ only. please help me in this manner.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations on this site, so they will be easier to read.

Comment: i need roots of h or value of h.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown please give me some comprehensive clue.

Comment: I removed the tag "root systems" and you reverted that edit. Please be aware that "root systems" are certain geometric-crystallographic objects which are used to classify certain Lie groups and Lie algebras: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system The tag description reads "For questions involving abstract root systems, their associated Weyl groups and Dynkin diagrams, as well as their applications to Lie theory, graph theory, or other related fields." They have nothing to do with your question, so my suggestion to remove that tag was well-founded and I would ask you to remove it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$h^2 .A=-144 . B h^{-1/2}$

$A^2 .h^4= 144^2. B^2. h^{-1}$

$A^2. h^5=144^2.B^2$

$h=(\frac{144^2.B^2}{A^2})^{1/5}$

Comment: thankx a lot for your help